# mssql@4.3.0 not working with SQL Server 2014

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2014

I'm currently using the mssql package version 4.3.0 in my Node.js project to connect to a SQL Server 2014 database. However, I'm experiencing difficulties establishing a connection. Here are the details of my setup:

mssql package version: 4.3.0
SQL Server version: SQL Server 2014
Node.js version: 12.13.0

I have confirmed that the connection details (server name, database, credentials) are correct. However, I receive an error message or encounter issues when trying to connect.

I've also tried other versions of the mssql package, such as 4.2.0 and 4.3.1, which have been reported to work with SQL Server 2014.

```
 message: 'Unable to connect with Database \n' +
    'ConnectionError: Failed to connect to IP:PORT in 15000ms',
  badge: true
```